# getting dialog to display utf-8

Tags: linux, utf-8, dialog, fedora

I built [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/) on fedora 11 (`./configure` then `make`), and it works great except for when I include characters with accents, umlauts, etc.  For example, ó becomes M-CM-3.

Is there something I could do to the build process or when running dialog to remedy this situation?

Comment: What's wrong with the dialog that comes with Fedora?

Comment: There is no such thing as "ASCII with accents, umlauts etc". ó is not an ASCII character.

Comment: Ignacio: I am packaging software for OLPC gnome which does not have dialog and need to include it.

Comment: The OLPC stuff is based on Fedora. Simply add it as a `Requires` in the package.

Comment: Ignacio -- a network connection is far from guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work (first "make distclean" of course):

```
   ./configure --with-ncursesw --enable-widec
```

also:
https://bkhome.org/archive/blog2/201104/dialog-11-20110302-busybox-1184.html

Comment: The original blog linked doesn't display its embedded images correctly; an archive.org copy can be found @ https://web.archive.org/web/20150421222701/http://bkhome.org/blog/?viewDetailed=02204